# how to exit from android app, my program redirect to the previous tab, used in the app

Tags: android

In my android app, i used tab for two different activity and a button in the first activity to close the app. but when i click on the button it redirect to the previous page..

```
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
onDestroy();

}
});

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    System.exit(0);
```

}

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/TBuJVev9V5k

Answer (score 1):

To close your app, whenever you start a new activity do it by using

```
    startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
```

And then in whichever Activity you are starting another Activity, use onActivityResult() as follows

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){              
            finish();
        }
    }
```

This will ensure that whenever you close an activity, the result is sent back to the parent Activity and it closes as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try write `finish();`in `OnClick()` method, not `onDestroy()`, and remove `System.exit(0);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your second activity

```
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();

           finish();
          }
```

and also add

```
 youractivity.this.finish()
```

in your on click method of cancel button.